# How can I reduce the number of get requests for s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cache, amazon-s3, apache2

I have an apache2 server living on an ec2 instance in AWS as well as an s3 bucket that holds mostly just image files.

What I want to do is implement some sort of caching for a user on my server or in the user's browser so I can reduce the number of get requests to save money, but I don't really know where to start. Is one better than the other? How would I go about this?

Comment: Put a CDN like CloudFront or CloudFlare in front of it.

Comment: Isn't cloudflare for server protection from attacks? How would cloudflare come into play?

Comment: Cloudfront looks like a good place to start though

Comment: CloudFlare does a lot of things. https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To improve caching at the client, use HTTP headers controlling caching and expiration.

Here is an introductory article on this. A google search will pop up a lot more information.

[Caching Headers and Amazon S3](http://blog.learningtree.com/image-caching-headers-and-amazon-s3/)